# MySQL/Django/Docker -> 1045, "1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'X'@'xx.xxx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)", '28000'

Tags: mysql, django, docker-compose, access-denied, mariadb-10.3

I have mariadb/mysql and django running as separate docker containers (both have separate docker-compose.yml files as well).

When I try to build my django docker container using `docker-compose build`(I have a Dockerfile defined for this with makemigrations and migrate commands in it) my container builds fine and correctly and `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` work fine as well.

However when I do `docker exec -ti <django-container-name> bash` and try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, it doesn't work.

I get a `1045, "1045 (28000): Access denied for user '<user>'@'<host>' (using password: YES)", '28000'`error.

Similarly, when I try to do `mysql -h <hostname> -P <port> -u <username> -p` I get a bash error saying that mysql doesn't exist (I also get this same error when i do just mysql).

Accessing MariaDB: When I do `docker exec -ti <mariadb-container-name> bash` and run the mysql command, I am able to see the migrations from the initial django build but nothing else after that.

Where am I going wrong that django can build and do makemigrations/migrate fine but won't run these commands inside the docker container once it is up and running?

I should clarify that mariadb/mysql and django are running on the same docker network but have different ipv4 addresses.

Comment: I assume you are getting an error on `mysql -h <hostname> ...` because you have no ports mapping between your machine and container. As for the migrations error, please include your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml`, the error may lie in build args or envs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.